# Is it possible to animate moving icons in deck.gl?

Tags: deck.gl

I've been visualizing trip data using a trips layer, and I'm trying to put an icon at the head of each trip line. Is it possible to make multiple icons change position, appear, and disappear over time?

[Example of what I'm trying to do (red arrow indicates motion over time)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D44qa.jpg)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking to do this for a while and achieved it following Mudkips answer.

I've appended animated icons to the TripsData example from the DeckGl site below.
Look at the IconLayer creation below, in particular that **getPosition** and **updateTriggers** portions.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Map} from 'react-map-gl';
import maplibregl from 'maplibre-gl';
import {AmbientLight, PointLight, LightingEffect} from '@deck.gl/core';
import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react';
import {PolygonLayer} from '@deck.gl/layers';
import {TripsLayer} from '@deck.gl/geo-layers';
import {IconLayer} from '@deck.gl/layers';

// Source data CSV
const DATA_URL = {
  BUILDINGS:
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visgl/deck.gl-data/master/examples/trips/buildings.json', // eslint-disable-line
  TRIPS: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visgl/deck.gl-data/master/examples/trips/trips-v7.json' // eslint-disable-line
};

const ambientLight = new AmbientLight({
  color: [255, 255, 255],
  intensity: 1.0
});

const pointLight = new PointLight({
  color: [255, 255, 255],
  intensity: 2.0,
  position: [-74.05, 40.7, 8000]
});

const lightingEffect = new LightingEffect({ambientLight, pointLight});

const material = {
  ambient: 0.1,
  diffuse: 0.6,
  shininess: 32,
  specularColor: [60, 64, 70]
};

const ICON_MAPPING = {
    marker: {x: 0, y: 0, width: 128, height: 128, mask: true}
  };

const DEFAULT_THEME = {
  buildingColor: [74, 80, 87],
  trailColor0: [253, 128, 93],
  trailColor1: [23, 184, 190],
  material,
  effects: [lightingEffect]
};

const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {
  longitude: -74,
  latitude: 40.72,
  zoom: 13,
  pitch: 45,
  bearing: 0
};

const MAP_STYLE = 'https://basemaps.cartocdn.com/gl/dark-matter-nolabels-gl-style/style.json';

const landCover = [
  [
    [-74.0, 40.7],
    [-74.02, 40.7],
    [-74.02, 40.72],
    [-74.0, 40.72]
  ]
];

export default function App({
  buildings = DATA_URL.BUILDINGS,
  trips = DATA_URL.TRIPS,
  trailLength = 180,
  initialViewState = INITIAL_VIEW_STATE,
  mapStyle = MAP_STYLE,
  theme = DEFAULT_THEME,
  loopLength = 1800, // unit corresponds to the timestamp in source data
  animationSpeed = 1,
  iconMapping = ICON_MAPPING
}) {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const [animation] = useState({});

  const animate = () => {
    setTime(t => (t + animationSpeed) % loopLength);
    animation.id = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    animation.id = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    return () => window.cancelAnimationFrame(animation.id);
  }, [animation]);

  const layers = [
    // This is only needed when using shadow effects
    new PolygonLayer({
      id: 'ground',
      data: landCover,
      getPolygon: f => f,
      stroked: false,
      getFillColor: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    }),
    new TripsLayer({
      id: 'trips',
      data: trips,
      getPath: d => d.path,
      getTimestamps: d => d.timestamps,
      getColor: d => (d.vendor === 0 ? theme.trailColor0 : theme.trailColor1),
      opacity: 0.5,
      widthMinPixels: 4,
      rounded: true,
      trailLength,
      currentTime: time,

      shadowEnabled: false
    }),
    new IconLayer({
        id: 'icon-layer',
        data: trips,
        iconAtlas: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visgl/deck.gl-data/master/website/icon-atlas.png', // Specify your icon atlas
        iconMapping: iconMapping, // Customize icon position
        sizeScale: 5, // Adjust icon size
        getColor: (d) => (d.vendor === 0 ? theme.trailColor0 : theme.trailColor1),
        getIcon: d => 'marker',
        getSize: d => 5,
        getPixelOffset: [0,-10],
        getPosition: (d) => {
          let x = null;
          let y = null;
          for(let i = 0; i < d.timestamps.length-1; i++) {
            if(time < d.timestamps[i + 1] && time >= d.timestamps[i]) {
              let frac = (time - d.timestamps[i]) / (d.timestamps[i+1] - d.timestamps[i]) 
              x = ((d.path[i+1][0] - d.path[i][0]) * frac) + d.path[i][0];
              y = ((d.path[i+1][1] - d.path[i][1]) * frac) + d.path[i][1];
              break;
            }               
          }
          return [x,y];        
        },
        updateTriggers: {
          getPosition: time
        }
      }),
    new PolygonLayer({
      id: 'buildings',
      data: buildings,
      extruded: true,
      wireframe: false,
      opacity: 0.5,
      getPolygon: f => f.polygon,
      getElevation: f => f.height,
      getFillColor: theme.buildingColor,
      material: theme.material
    })
  ];

  return (
    <DeckGL
      layers={layers}
      effects={theme.effects}
      initialViewState={initialViewState}
      controller={true}
    >
      <Map reuseMaps mapLib={maplibregl} mapStyle={mapStyle} preventStyleDiffing={true} />
    </DeckGL>
  );
}
```

Comment: Note this approach works for TextLayer and ScatterplotLayer too

Answer (score -1):

Simply animate the data's position property, making sure it's a state change to trigger rerenders, before giving it to the layer. You can also put opacity in the data and animate that too.